# Headless OpenGL rendering on Google Compute

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, x-server, google-cloud

I created a GPU instance on Google Compute engine with NVIDIA Tesla K80 attached.
I have installed GPU drivers and CUDA based on this [guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-a-gpu-tensorflow-on-google-cloud-platform-1a2458f42b0).

nvidia-smi check - **ok.**

nvcc -V check - **ok**

Now I am trying to make sure I can run headless rendering with OpenGL.

I tried this:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=none
```

to configure xconfig.

Then:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Finally,running glxgears:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

I am getting this error:

> No protocol specified Error: unable to open display :0

My xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.30  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Wed Jan 31 22:46:17 PST 2018
Section "ServerFlags"
     Option "IgnoreABI" "True"
     Option "nolisten" "True"
     Option "AutoAddDevices" "False"
EndSection
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "nvidia" 0 0
EndSection
Section "Files"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Tesla K80"
    BusID          "PCI:0:4:0"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

What is missing in my config?

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Your setup misses a running X server.

Comment: Looking, closer, it seems to me you have an X server running, but authentication failed. You need to provide X cookie with `XAUTHORITY` or run `xhost +SI:localuser:yourusername` on X. How do you start X?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?